# WordPress Installation showing error message in iPage Hosting

Tags: php, wordpress, installation

Hello i am new baby in `wordpress` CMS.

I bought `iPage` Hosting for my website.

When i installed wordpress to my hosting , this error message is showing.

```
Server Response Empty
Your server responded with a blank page, which means your server is having difficulties processing PHP requests. If you are not familiar with this error (potentially a "500" Error), please contact your server admin or web host about possible resolutions.
```

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"500" error indicate that it's Internal Server Error.**

**Cause of HTTP 500 Errors**

The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that means something has gone wrong on the web site's server but the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is.

Most of the time, "gone wrong" means an issue with the page or site's programming, nothing you have anything to do with.

**How To Fix the 500 Internal Server Error**
The 500 Internal Server Error is a server-side error, meaning the problem probably isn't with your computer or Internet connection but instead is a problem with the web site's server.

While not probable, it is possible that there's something wrong on your end and we'll look at some things you can try.

Reload the web page. You can do that by clicking the refresh/reload button, pressing F5, or trying the URL again from the address bar.

Even if the 500 Internal Server Error is a problem on the web server, the issue may only be temporary. Trying the page again will often be successful.

Clear your browser's cache. If there's a problem with the cached version of the page you're viewing, it could be causing HTTP 500 issues.

Note: Internal Server Errors are not often caused by caching issues but I have, on occasion, seen the error go away after clearing the cache. It's such an easy and harmless thing to try so don't skip it.

Delete your browser's cookies. Some 500 Internal Server Error issues can be corrected by deleting the cookies associated with the site you're getting the error on.

After removing the cookie(s), restart the browser and try again.

It's not very common, but some servers produce a 500 Internal Server Error when in reality the more appropriate message based on the cause of the problem is 504 Gateway Timeout.

Contact the website directly. Chances are good that the website administrators already know about the 500 error but if you suspect they don't, letting them know helps both you and them (and everyone else).

The best way to find contact information for a website is through a WHOIS search, using the domain name as your search term.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you need to go into your files and delete the .htaccess. A new one will automatically replace it and it will fix the issue. If you can't find the .htaccess or whichever server file your host is using, contact them to remove it. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is a temporary fix in the Visual Composer plugin itself. However the next update will address it from the Theme side and will not have to rely on Visual Composer adding a check for it.

Locate the following file on your server: /wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/core/class-wpb-map.php

Unzip and replace it with this file:

http://help.themeva.com/tmp/class-wpb-map.php.zip